# SQL / SAS: create table where not exist?

Tags: sql, create-table, not-exists

i have a table like this:

```
ID    GROUP VALUE
201540  1   1000
201540  2   1111
201540  5   2000
201550  1   200
201550  8   400
201610  4   990
201610  5   400
201610  6   777
201610  7   222
201610  8   6666
```

What I Need to do is to expand the table, so each ID has 8 Groups from 1 to 8.
I want to create a table conaining the missing Groups for each ID, like this:

```
ID    GROUP VALUE
201540  3   -1
201540  4   -1
201540  6   -1
201540  7   -1
201540  8   -1
201550  2   -1
201550  3   -1
201550  4   -1
201550  5   -1
201550  6   -1
201550  7   -1
201610  1   -1
201610  2   -1
201610  3   -1
```

I tried with

```
CREATE TABLE TMP AS 
SELECT ID, GROUP, -1 from table where not exists
(SELECT * FROM table where ....)
```

But I don't know how to use the `where-clause`...

any hints?
thank you, dbdb

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried in Oracle. The logic is

1. Generate range from 1-8. (seq)
2. Get distinct ID in a derived table. (dist)
3. Cross join the above 2 outputs to get all possible combination of Group and ID.
4. Use this combination and join with existing table and filter only those records which are missing in existing table. You can do it with `left join`.

This is the sample code in Oracle. You can use similar approach in SAS.

```
    with tbl(ID,GRP,VAL) as (
    select 201540,1,1000 from dual union all
    select 201540,2,1111 from dual union all
    select 201540,5,2000 from dual union all
    select 201550,1,200  from dual union all
    select 201550,8,400  from dual union all
    select 201610,4,990  from dual union all
    select 201610,5,400  from dual union all
    select 201610,6,777  from dual union all
    select 201610,7,222  from dual union all
    select 201610,8,6666 from dual )
    ,seq (seqno) as (
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual union all
    select 3 from dual union all
    select 4 from dual union all
    select 5 from dual union all
    select 6 from dual union all
    select 7 from dual union all
    select 8 from dual)
    ,all_seq as 
    (select * from seq cross join (select distinct ID from tbl))
    select s.id,s.seqno as grp,-1 as val from all_seq s
    left join tbl t 
    on s.id=t.id and s.seqno=t.grp
    where t.id is null
```

Output

```
ID      GRP VAL
201540  4   -1
201540  7   -1
201540  6   -1
201540  3   -1
201540  8   -1
201550  7   -1
201550  4   -1
201550  3   -1
201550  5   -1
201550  6   -1
201550  2   -1
201610  1   -1
201610  3   -1
201610  2   -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in SAS then it might be easiest to break the problem down into a few steps like this:

1. Get a list if all the unique IDs (skip this step if you already have a dataset like this already)

`Proc sort data = original out = ID_list nodupkey;

    by ID;

    run;`

2. Expand the ID list dataset to contain all groups for each ID.

   `data expanded;

      set ID_list;

         do i = 1 to 8;

           group = i;

           value = - 1;

           output;

         end;

   run;`
3. Find ID*Group combinations not present in original.

   `proc sql;

     create table final as

     select L.*

     from expanded as L left join original as R

     on L.ID=R.ID and L.group = R.group

     where not(L.ID = R.ID and L.group = R.group);

   quit;`

This should give you all the ID*Groups not present in the original dataset with - 1 as the value.

Comment: thank you very much, yes it is in SAS. Your solution works for me.